# Cambiar condicion

Tags: ruby, condiciones

Alguna alternativa para este `if`, me interesa usar `"?"` pero no se como utilizar la condicional y remplazar el `if`

```
if @answer.ok_answer == true 
  @answer.ok_answer = false 
else 
  @answer.ok_answer = true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que esta mal tu pregunta por que allí solo tendrías que setear el valor en negativo:

```
@answer.ok_answer = !@answer.ok_answer
```

el if se utiliza:
     `(condicion)?valorCumple:valorNoCumple`

```
(x=1)?"Cumple":"No Cumple"
```

Comment: Lo que pusiste en tu ejemplo no es código ruby válido, que es por lo que consulta el OP en la pregunta.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827874/one-line-if-statement-not-working

Comment: yo veo que lo que quieres es invertir el valor, cuando es true poner false y cuando es false colocar true, es un simple not (!)

Comment: Yo no hice la pregunta. Me refería a `string a` (que ya sacaste) no es código ruby válido.

Comment: es correcto el string se me fue por eso ya no esta solo seria tu variable =